# Show that S is non-compact and deduce further that the closed unit ball in X is non-compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I have an exercise I am not sure how to solve
The exercise is:
Let X be an infinite dimensional normed vector space over $\mathbb{K}$ where $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{C}$. Define the unit sphere $S=\{x \in X : \|x\|=1\}$

Show that S is non-compact and deduce further that the closed unit ball in X is non-compact.

I am not sure how to show that S is non-compact, but for the second part where I have to deduce that the closed unit ball in X is non-compact (I denote closed unit ball in X by B)  I am thinking that I will show B is compact $\Rightarrow$ X is finite.

I assume that B is compact and then since S is a closed subset of B, then S will be compact and then I can use the first part to say that X may be finite. So now I have shown that B is compact $\Rightarrow$ X is finite, hence if X is infinite then B is non-compact. But I have troubles showing that S is non-compact, so I was hoping that someone could help me with that. We have already shown following:

[image]

Comment: Choose a basis of unit length vectors $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathcal{I}}$ and use it to construct a sequence in $S$ with no convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 3):

Your Problem 3, (d) implies that $S$ is not compact.

Indeed, assume that $S$ is compact and for any $x\in S$ consider $B_x=\{v\in X\ |\ \lVert x-v\rVert < 1/2\}$. Then $\{B_x\}_{x\in S}$ is an open covering of $S$ and by compactness it has to contain a finite subcover $\{B_{x_1}, \ldots, B_{x_n}\}$. But then $\{\overline{B_{x_1}},\ldots, \overline{B_{x_n}}\}$ is a closed ball covering of $S$ and none of them contains $0$, contradicting Problem 3, (d).

Finally the closed ball cannot be compact as well because $S$ is its closed subset. And a closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Also, please do you use full "finite dimensional" and "infinite dimensional" instead of "finite" and "infinite" to avoid confusion. It took me some time to figure out that you are not talking about literally finite sets.

Comment: How do we know that $\{B_x\}_{x\in S}$ is an open covering of S? For $\{B_x\}_{x\in S}$  to be able to be a covering of S, we have to have $S\subset \bigcup_{x\in S} B_x$. And for this to apply we have to have that $x\in S\Rightarrow x\in \bigcup_{x\in S} \{B_x\}_{x\in S} $ i.e $\|x\|=1$ for $x\in X$ $\Rightarrow \|x-v\|<\frac{1}{2}$ . But if we assume $x\in S$ we have $\|x-v\|\leq \|x\|-\|v\|=1-\|v\|$. And how do we know $1-\|v\|<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @Hello simply because $x\in B_x$ for any $x\in S$. Note that $\lVert x-x\rVert =0 <1/2$. After all our $B_x$ is an open ball around $x$ of radius $1/2$, and so it has to contain at least $x$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. And now I am wondering, the reason why $\lbrace \overline{B_{x_1}},...,\overline{B_{x_n}}\rbrace$ is a closed covering of S is it because since $B_{x_i} \subset \overline{B_{x_i}}$ for all i=1,...,n it applies that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_{x_i}\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline {B_{x_i}}$ and since $B_{x_i}$ is a finite subcover we will have that $S \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n B_{x_i}$. Hence $S\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n \overline{B_{x_i}}$

Comment: How do we know that none of them contains $0$?

Comment: @Hello yes, that's because $B_x\subseteq\overline{B_x}$ and (in normed spaces) closure of an open ball is a closed ball. In fact $\overline{B_x}=\{v\in X\ |\ \lVert x-v\rVert \leq 1/2\}$ which I encourage you to prove yourself. We know that $B_x$ doesn't contain $0$ because $\Vert x\rVert=1$ (as an element of $S$) and so $\lVert x-0\rVert=\lVert x\rVert=1>1/2$.

Comment: Now you says that $B_x\subset \overline {B_x}$ but do you mean $B_{x_i}\subset \overline {B_{x_i}}$?

Comment: @Hello dude, $x$ and $x_i$ are just symbols. $x_i$ is one of $x$. And the inclusion works for any $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$(1).$ Suppose $Y$ is a closed vector-subspace of $X$ and $x\in X$ \ $Y.$ Let $d(x,Y)=\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\|$. Take $z\in Y$ with $$(*)...\quad \|x-z\|<2d(x,Y).$$ Let $w=(x-z)/\|x-z\|.$ Then we have $$(**)...\quad d(w, Y)=\inf_{y\in Y}\|w-y\|=\|x-z\|^{-1}\inf_{y\in Y}\|\,(x-(z+y\|x-z\|)\,\|.$$ Now $\{z+y\|x-z\|:y\in Y\}=Y.$ So $\inf_{y\in Y} \|(x-(z+y\|x-z\|)\|=\inf_{y\in Y}\|x-y\|=d(x,Y).$ So from $(*)$ & $(**)$ we have $$d(w,Y)=\|x-z\|^{-1}d(x,Y)>\|x-z\|^{-1}\|x-z\|/2=1/2.$$

So if $Y$ is a closed vector-subspace of $X$ and $Y\ne X$ then there exists $w\in X$ \ $Y$ with $\|w\|=1$ and $d(w,Y)>1/2.$

$(2).$ Prove that if $Y$ is a finite-dimensional vector-subspace of $X$ then $Y$ is closed.

$(3).$ If $X$ is infinite-dimensional: Take $y_1\in X$  with $\|y_1\|=1.$ Recursively for $n\in \Bbb N$ let $Y_n=Span(y_1,...,y_n)$ and by $(1)$ & $(2)$ take $y_{n+1}\in X$ \ $Y_n$ with $\|y_{n+1}\|=1$ and $d(y_{n+1}, Y_n)>1/2.$

Let $T=\{y_n:n\in \Bbb N\}.$ Then $T$ is an infinite set and $\|y-y'\|>1/2$ for any  distinct $y,y'\in T.$ So $T$ is an infinite closed discrete topological-subspace of $X.$

Consider $X, S$, and the closed unit ball $B$ as metric spaces with the metric $e(u,v)=\|u-v\|.$ Then $T$ is an infinite closed discrete topological-subspace of $S$ and of $B.$ Any metric space with such a topological-subspace cannot be compact.

[... Any subset of a closed discrete topological-subspace is also closed. So if $U_n=X\setminus \{y_j:j\ge n\}$ then $\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is an open cover of $S$ (and of $B$) with no finite subcover...].

Remarks: In $(1)$ we could take $z\in Y$ with $\|x-z\|$ arbitrarily close to $d(x,Y)$ and hence $d(w,Y)$ can be arbitrarily close to $1.$ And if $Y$ is finite-dimensional we can show there exists $z\in Y$ with $d(x,Y)=\|x-z\|$ and hence $d(w, Y)=1$.